# Using sympy to calculate the exact values of sin and cos of (m/n)*pi

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to find the exact values of the sine and cosine of a good amount of the rational values*pi. I am doing this mostly to learn new mathematics and python. This is the code I came up with, which works pretty well (under certain conditions).

```py
from sympy import *
import sympy
from IPython.display import display
from sympy.abc import k, m, n, x
import math
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing() 
print("You are solving for sin and cos of (m/n)pi")
m = int(input("Insert m: "))
n = int(input("Insert n: "))
gcd = sympy.gcd(m,n) #Getting the GCD and dividing by it will make the algorithm have less steps
m = m/gcd
n = n/gcd
prime = primefactors(n) #this outputs an array of all of the factors of n
cosp = sympify(-1) #this is necessary, we set the value of cos(pi) = -1, and format it for sympy
r = int(1)
for p in prime:#the nested loops will go through every factor. The for loop each of the factors,
    while n%p == 0:#the while loop for the repetition of the factors
        r = int(r*p)#the r variable serves as a comparison for the values of the cosine
        n = int(n/p)#dividing by the prime we're checking for will complete the loop
        if p == 2:
            cosp = sqrt((1+cosp)/2)#simple bisection of the cosine formula
        else:
            cosp = (Sum((-1)**k*factorial(p)/(factorial(p-2*k)*factorial(2*k))*x**(p-2*k)*(1-x**2)**k , (k, 0, int((p-1)/2)))).doit()-cosp #check out this explanation: https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/. This is a version of the cosine formula, where x symbolizes cosine pi, and we bring the cosine value to the other side to get "0 = F(x)"
            expandeq = expand(cosp)
            res = solve(expandeq) #we solve for the roots of the equation
            for root in res:
                if N(sympy.cos(sympy.pi/r), 15) == re(N(root, 15)): #to remove all extra solutions, we check the approximation of each root and verify it is equal to cos(pi/r)
                    if str(root)[0] != "C":
                        cosp = root
sinp = expand(sqrt(1-(cosp**2))) 

cosm = expand(Sum((-1)**k*factorial(m)/(factorial(m-(2*k))*factorial(2*k))*cosp**(m-2*k)*sinp**(2*k) , (k, 0, int(m/2))).doit(), trig = False) #finally, we use the formula again to multiply the cosine of pi/n by m
sinm = expand(sympy.sqrt(1-(cosm**2)), trig=False)
print("Approximation of sine of pi*",m, "/",r,": " , round(math.sin(math.pi*m/r), 15))
display(sinm)
print("Approximation of of cosine pi*",m, "/",r,": " , round(math.cos(math.pi*m/r), 15))
display(cosm)
```

This works, for pretty much any m, but for very limited n. Here is a list of some prime values it can accept: {2,3,5,7,11}. It can solve for any n in form 2^k*3^l (such as n = 144), but it stops at a measly 25, as it outputs a quintic equation :16x^5-20x^3+5x-sqrt(5)/4-1/4, where one solution does correspond to the cosine of pi/25. Is there a way to fix this? How can I expand the "domain" of this code?

Btw, the purpose of this code is to learn, any references to specific math formulas, procedures, manuscripts or theries (like galois theory, quite a bit to unpack for a HS student) is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "fix this".  It has done exactly what you asked it to do -- find a solution to your equation.

Comment: You also might look into [`nsimplify()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html) which approximates a floating point number with a symbolic expression

Comment: Your test `if N(sympy.cos(sympy.pi/r), 15) == re(N(root, 15))` can be cumbersome.  It tests for exact equality, while the two values might be extremely close. You might try [`math.isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) instead.

Comment: In practice you can't - at least not in the way you are hoping. Only some quintics can be solved in closed form and many have to be solved numerically. Quartics and cubic equations will yield to pure analytical solutions with varying degrees of difficulty. Maxima or Mathematica might be a more user friendly way for you to play about with your ideas (both have fairly steep learning curves but you seem to have done quite well on your own so far with sympy). Try asking again on the maths version of SO.

Comment: Very very relevant: [For which values of θ does sin(θ) etc have closed form solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133172/for-which-values-of-theta-does-sin-theta-etc-have-closed-form-solutions)

Comment: And [Exact value of sin(pi sqrt(2))?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351481/exact-value-of-sin-pi-sqrt-2) has some completing information.

Answer (score 3):

For any integers `n` and `m` the numbers `cos(n/m*pi)` and `sin(n/m*pi)` will be algebraic numbers meaning that they are roots of polynomials with rational coefficients. That does not necessarily mean that such numbers can be represented using explicit expressions in radicals though because this is not possible for all algebraic numbers due to the Abel-Ruffini theorem.

What SymPy can do however for any `m` and `n` is tell you the polynomial that such a number is a root of (the minimal polynomial):

```
>>> print(minpoly(sin(5*pi/13)))
4096*_x**12 - 13312*_x**10 + 16640*_x**8 - 9984*_x**6 + 2912*_x**4 - 364*_x**2 + 13
```

SymPy's `roots` function is intended to obtain radical expressions for roots when possible but it fails in this case (probably because no such radical expressions exist). Instead though SymPy has a way to represent any algebraic number as "RootOf". In this case that looks like:

```
In [53]: [rs] = [r for r in real_roots(p) if p.same_root(r, sin(5*pi/13))]

In [54]: rs
Out[54]: 
       ⎛      12          10          8         6         4        2         ⎞
CRootOf⎝4096⋅x   - 13312⋅x   + 16640⋅x  - 9984⋅x  + 2912⋅x  - 364⋅x  + 13, 10⎠
```

This tells us that `sin(5*pi/13)` is the 10th root of the given polynomial (according to SymPy's root numbering scheme). This RootOf representation is an exact representation of the number although some might not consider it to be "explicit". We can for example compute this number to any desired precision and also obtain its minimal polynomial:

```
In [55]: rs.evalf(50)
Out[55]: 0.93501624268541482343978459983783072905051746957843

In [56]: print(minpoly(rs))
4096*_x**12 - 13312*_x**10 + 16640*_x**8 - 9984*_x**6 + 2912*_x**4 - 364*_x**2 + 13
```

This is an exact representation of the number because it has sufficient information to perform exact calculations. The RootOf representation can represent all algebraic numbers and is often a better representation even when radical expressions are possible.

You asked for the "exact values" and I've shown `rs` which is an exact representation of the number. However we started with an exact value in the original expression `sin(5*pi/13)` which most people would probably prefer over the RootOf representation `rs`.

The question then is if the original expression was not what you wanted then how do you define what you do want?

Comment: Thank you! This is an amazing answer,  but I was looking for the radical expressions. RootOf is the better way to represent this answer, and having the sin approximated to any digit is going to always be enough in any practical application, but this isn't practical. This is maybe more a math question than a programming question? Asking how to create an automated way to solve the answers of this solvable quintic (and beyond) group, as they are always express able as radicals. I'll probably ask the question again in the math stack overflow

Comment: PS the sin and cosine of a rational number is always express able as a radical, sometimes constructible in the case of the Fermat primes, usually not, as they belong to a cyclotomic field https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Cyclotomic_polynomials

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case if you are happy with complex radicals what is wrong with `sin(5*pi/13) = ((-1)**(8/13) + (-1)**(5/13))/(2*i)`?

Comment: Well, nothing is wrong with it, but it is a bit of a boring answer hahaha. Maybe it's me being picky, but answering for the sin and cosine like this doesn't give a lot of information to the user